# Adding only new or modified data to a redshift table

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Every month I receive a tsv with data. I need a table that reflects the data in this tsv. Every row in this table will have the date of the day it was added. The tsv may be exactly the same as the tsv from the previous month, in which case none of the data in the table will be changed. The data may also have a modified row from that of the previous month, in which case we need to update that row and also change the date column with todays date. Or finally, we may just have new data, in which case add this new data to the table with todays date. Wondering what the easiest way to do this is. Currently already have python using the COPY command to write a tsv file to redshift but need help with the correct sql command to update the table.

Example:

Current table:

```
9/1/2020  Mike 3  
9/1/2020  Jake 4
```

New tsv file:

```
10/1/2020  Mike 5  
10/1/2020  Kevin 4
```

Table after we add new tsv data:

```
9/1/2020  Jake 4
10/1/2020  Mike 5  
10/1/2020  Kevin 4
```

Comment: Is there any additional data in the table, aside from what is coming in the TSV file? If not, why not simply replace the whole table with the contents of the TSV file?

Comment: Did you try: [Updating and inserting new data - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_updating-inserting-using-staging-tables-.html)

Comment: I want to try and maintain the dates of when data was added/modified

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestions given on [Performing a merge operation by replacing existing rows - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/merge-replacing-existing-rows.html), a typical process is:

- Load the data into a temporary staging table
- Delete rows that need to be replaced (`DELETE FROM target USING stage WHERE target.primarykey = stage.primarykey`)
- Copy data across (`INSERT INTO target SELECT * FROM stage`)

You'll need to modify the process slightly to insert today's date on those new rows.